# How to generate two columns in loop on asp net view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach, view

I would like to get two columns side by side in one row. Data in these columns will be different.

Like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      Data1 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
      Data2
  </div>
</div>
```

But.. my code generate a structure:

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">

                <h2>Title: </h2>
                <p>Position: Name Surname</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <h2>Title: </h2>
                <p>Position: Name Surname</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">

        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my code in PartialView (_Pozycjee.cshtml):

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>

@if (Model.Any() == true)
{

    foreach (dynamic item in Model)
    {
        @:<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            @if (item.Mecz.GospodarzKlubId == item.Zawodnik.KlubId)
            {
                <h2>Skład gospodarzy:</h2>
                <p>@item.Nazwa: @item.Zawodnik.Imie @item.Zawodnik.Nazwisko</p>
            }
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">

            @if (item.Mecz.GoscKlubId == item.Zawodnik.KlubId)
            {
                <h2>Skład gości:</h2>
                <p>@item.Nazwa: @item.Zawodnik.Imie @item.Zawodnik.Nazwisko</p>
            }
        </div>
    }
   @: </div>

}
else
{
    <p>Brak pozycji</p>
}
```

This generate a "empty" div and and spoils everything.
Look at this screen: https://photoland.io/i/k4Pzu

Please for Help. Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>

@if (Model.Any() == true)
{
  <div class="row">
    @foreach (dynamic item in Model)
    {
        if (item.Mecz.GospodarzKlubId == item.Zawodnik.KlubId)
        {
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <h2>Skład gospodarzy:</h2>
                <p>@item.Nazwa: @item.Zawodnik.Imie @item.Zawodnik.Nazwisko</p>
            </div>
        }


        if(item.Mecz.GoscKlubId == item.Zawodnik.KlubId)
        {
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <h2>Skład gości:</h2>
                <p>@item.Nazwa: @item.Zawodnik.Imie @item.Zawodnik.Nazwisko</p>
            </div>
        }
    }
 </div>
}
else
{
    <p>Brak pozycji</p>
}
```

Comment: Where from 0:6 coming? How have you placed this? May be this is causing problem. I have check my code in my side. its working as expected.

Comment: can You give me Your any contact? Mail or something? I have a question.